# HTML page to Image using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, google-chrome, screenshot

**Problem:**

I would like to convert an HTML page into an image. But when I use my PowerShell code the generated image is the part of the HTML not whole HTML due to overflow.

**My PowerShell Code:**

```
& 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe' `
--headless --disable-gpu --screenshot=D:\Html\screenshot.png `
file:///D:/Html/New.html
```

**Generated Image:**

[image]

Please suggest how I can handle it to get whole image.

Comment: try adding the command line argument to change the window size `--window-size=1280,1696` source: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome

Comment: This is not really a PowerShell-specific thing (as you're not using any PowerShell Cmdlets) but just a Chrome command-line question. This question belongs on SuperUser.com.

Comment: Hi @JoSSte, Thank you for the solution. using this solution i'm getting unwanted space at the end of the image which i don't want. Is there any way to identify the exact height and width of the Html page on browser view?

Comment: I don't think  you will find anything built in. I would have a look at something like Puppeteer https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer which is an API built for the headless Chrome. maybe that could inspire you. unfortunately this is not Powershell but nodejs